# Why "some one who 'incorrects my English'" "incorrects my English" is a word play?

Tags: word-play

According to the comment of Kent Anderson to this question:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/44581/26185

> Q: **How to deal with a customer who “incorrects” my English?**
>
> the title to this question is superb ("incorrects my
> English"). It does show a certain level of mastery of a language when
> you can start playing with the words like that!

"incorrects my English" is a word play.

I'm not that good at speaking English, but knew of the phrase.
But didn't know that it is a word play. In how far it is?

Comment: *Correct* can be used as an adjective and a verb, whereas *incorrect* is (as far as I know) normally used as an adjective. The way *incorrects* is used in that sentence, though non-standard, is obviously intentional, and the intended meaning is clear (that it's opposite to the verb *correct*, i.e. instead of turning mistakes into good and correct sentences, that someone who made "incorrections" turned good and correct sentences into incorrect ones).

Comment: Have you looked up "word play" in Wikipedia or a dictionary? What is it about the definition that you do not understand?

Comment: +1 solely for the ***verb*** 'incorrect'. I loved it and will use it! :)

Comment: @pazzo: Well, they were talking in the comments of the linked post, about playing with words. I'm from germany and wordplay is 1:1 translation of the german word, if wordplay is something different from the result of playing around with words, then I'm sorry. But no, I dodn't look it up.

Comment: @MaulikV: Ah, I guess I got it. so grammatically, there doesn't exist the verb 'to incorrect' as opposite to 'to correct' while the oppsoite of the adjective 'correct' is obvisiously 'incorrect'? Did I get that right? I never thought about it and it felt to me, that 'to incorrect' can be used as intuitive as the same adjective. ^^

Comment: Yes, that's not incorrect. Do don't let someone incorrect you.

Comment: @Zaibis you got it! ;) haha

Comment: In German, it would be "verschlimmbessern". Which actually made it into www.duden.de.

Comment: @MaulikV You shouldn't use it. "Uncorrect" is better. :) "Incorrect" would be an adjective. "Uncorrect" would be the verb. (Neither one is a word in common usage, though.)

Comment: Sorry, I had a braindead moment earlier. "Incorrect" is of course a commonly used word. It's just not the right form of the word Ken meant to employ in his word play.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, someone who thought he knew how to speak better English, "corrected" a statement that did not need correcting, thereby offering an "Incorrect correction".

Answer (score -2):

It's very common among native English speakers that one person who thinks he knows the language better than another person will publicly correct the other person's mistakes. It happens sometimes, though, that the person doing the correcting is actually wrong (but believes himself very strongly to be right). In linguistics, this is known as [hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection).

When Kent Anderson uses the phrase "incorrect my English", he's playing on the idea of the common practice of one person correcting another's language--or "correcting my English". Ken used the wrong prefix, though, as the prefix "in-" would turn the word into an adjective. What Ken means to do is keep it as a verb but turn its meaning around, to refer to individuals who demonstrate hypercorrection by erroneously correcting Ken's usage when Ken's usage is *actually* correct. To accomplish this better, he should have used the prefix "un-", as in "uncorrect my English".

But there's the answer for you. Ken's use of this peculiar phrase refers to individuals who demonstrate tendencies of hypercorrection. This works as a play on words because the concept of hypercorrection is *very* well known among native English speakers, mostly because there are so many different dialects of English, most of which tend to assume that their ways of speaking and writing are the *best* ways.

Comment: -1 for absolute wrong explanation of hypercorrection. -1 again for insisting that *un-* has anything whatsoever to do with using *incorrect* as a verb. One could just as easily make that claim for *de-*.

Comment: This is not what hypercorrection is

Comment: @pazzo "Uncorrect" is the normal way to say what "incorrect" says with word play. Also, most bogus corrections of the sort described are hypercorrections, though not all (and, as you say, the explanation is wrong).